# How to get param from url in getStaticProps without using getStaticPaths?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Here is my function below in which I am using the getServerSideProps() method and fetch data dynamically according to the param post_slug from my URL.

```
// This gets called on every request
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
  const { post_slug } = query || {};

  let url = API_URLS.POST.GET_POST_BY_SLUG;

  url = url.replace(/#POST_SLUG#/g, post_slug);

  const res = await fetch(url);
  const { data } = (await res.json()) || {};

  // Pass post_data to the page via props
  return { props: { data } };
}
```

But this function render a whole page on every request.

So now I decide to use getStaticProps() but here I could not get param post_slug from URL.

I read [next js](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) documentation where they tell I need to use getStaticPaths() along getStaticProps() method but here the problem is I have to define static params in getStaticPaths() method but I want param from my current URL.

Is there any solution to get param post_slug from URL in the getStaticProps() method?

Answer (score 11):

You can do so using `getStaticPaths` with `fallback` set to `true` to get params(not query) and create the static page at request time.

In that case, when visitors visit paths that have not been generated at build time, Next.js will serve a "fallback" version of the page on the first request to such a path (It can simply be `<div>Loading...</div>`)

Next.js will then run `getStaticProps` and build the page and data json for the first time and serve to the visitor when ready.

Next.js also adds this path to the list of pre-rendered pages so subsequent requests to the same path will serve the generated page, just like other pages pre-rendered at build time.

In your case, you can't simply swap out `getServerSideProps` with `getStaticPaths`. You will have to create a `[postSlug].js` to use the param `postSlug`.

```
// Example code
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

function Post({ post }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  if (router.isFallback)  return <div>Loading...</div>;
  // Render post...
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [{ params: { postSlug: 'sth' } }, { params: { postSlug: 'sth-else' } }],
    fallback: true,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../posts/${params.postSlug}`);
  const post = await res.json();
  return {
    props: { post },
  }
}

export default Post;
```

To update the statically generated pages, check out [Next.js Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-5#stable-incremental-static-regeneration)

Comment: Isn't it a problem that you have to add every single possible URL to getStaticPaths? In this case `postSlug`. what if you have hundreds or thousands?

Comment: Usually, you will get them from database, e.g. `const postSlugs = await Post.findMany()`, then map the result to `paths.

Comment: Hi Can I get support for this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67591370/next-i18next-translations-with-dynamic-id-and-query-param

Answer (score 8):

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [],
    // Enable statically generating additional pages
    // For example: `/posts/3`
    fallback: true,
  }
}
```

This piece of information is already mentioned in docs, [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#when-is-fallback-true-useful).

Quoting the docs:

> fallback: true is useful if your app has a very large number of static
> pages that depend on data (think: a very large e-commerce site). You
> want to pre-render all product pages, but then your builds would take
> forever.
>
> Instead, you may statically generate a small subset of pages and use
> fallback: true for the rest. When someone requests a page that’s not
> generated yet, the user will see the page with a loading indicator.
> Shortly after, getStaticProps finishes and the page will be rendered
> with the requested data. From now on, everyone who requests the same
> page will get the statically pre-rendered page.
>
> This ensures that users always have a fast experience while preserving
> fast builds and the benefits of Static Generation.

If you don't want to show Loader state but instead want to show Browser requesting page(first time only, will be added in pre-generated pages for consecutive req.) [fallback:"blocking"](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fallback-blocking)

**For Development, getStaticPaths and getStaticProps will be called on every request.**

Answer (score 1):

You cant.
`getStaticProps` will fetch data at **build time** and  you won’t be able to use data that’s only available during request time, such as query parameters or HTTP headers.
If your page shows frequently updated data and/or dynamic content you should use **Server-side Rendering** instead.
it actually depends on what you need to pre-render,remember that you can still use the `Router` and fetch the data inside `componentDidMount` or `useEffect`

Answer (score 1):

use `getServerSideProps`. `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` are used to generate static pages to prerender. Let's say you have blogs in the database, you fetch the blogs, get paths and passed them to `getStaticProps`.

In your case, `context` object is passed to `getServerSideProps`, and you can reach the params.id as follow:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  return { props: { paramsId: context.params.id } };
};
```

Now, when you make a requst, next.js will pass the "paramsId" to the client and you can reach it inside component with `props.paramsId`

Comment: Hi, Can I get support for this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67591370/next-i18next-translations-with-dynamic-id-and-query-param

Comment: I wouldn't say getServerSideProps is for generate static pages

Comment: @utopia I did not say that. there is a dot after `use getServerSideProps`

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot access the user request in `getStaticProps`** because in this case the page is created once at **build time**.

**But** `getStaticPathes` completely solves your problem **if you set fallback equal to 'blocking'** because whenever the user searches for a page for the first time, that page is created and saved with the parameters of that request.

**If fallback is 'blocking'**, new paths not returned by `getStaticPaths` will wait for the HTML to be generated, identical to SSR (hence why blocking), and then be cached for future requests so it only happens once per path.

**If you don't want to use `getStaticPaths`**, you can handle that part of the page whose data depends on the url as csr (client side rendering) by using `useEffect`;

It is better for you to read the following document to get a better understanding
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).