# NextJS getStaticProps() is not called after params change

Tags: typescript, next.js

In my web app, front end is conected with Contentful cms to gather data about some products.

This is part of my directory configuration /pages/[category]/items/[id]

Inside /pages/[category] is located Index.tsx with some code:

```
// Page component

interface ProductsIndexProps {
    products: ProductItemModel[],
    totalPages: number,
    currentPage: number
}

export default function ProductsIndex(props: ProductsIndexProps) {

    const { products, totalPages, currentPage } = props;

    const router = useRouter();

    return (
        <div>
            <div className={styles.title_section}>
                <h2 className={styles.title}>Results for all items</h2>
            </div>

            <div className={styles.list_container}>
                <section className={styles.list_sidebar}></section>
                <ProductList
                    products={products}
                    category={asString(router.query.category || "") || ""}
                    currentPage={currentPage}
                    totalPages={totalPages}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

...
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {

    return {
        paths: [
            { params: { category: "laptops" } },
            { params: { category: "motorcycle" } },
            { params: { category: "accessories" } },
        ],
        fallback: false,
    }
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {

    const category = context.params?.category || "";
    const productsData = await getPaginatedProducts(1, category);
    const envPag = process.env.pagination || '0';
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(productsData.total / parseInt(envPag));

    return {
        props: {
            products: productsData.items,
            totalPages,
            currentPage: 1
        },
    }
}
```

All I want is to, dependly on "category" param, call getPaginatedProducts and send data to my page [category].tsx.

**What I want**, when I head to /laptops -> getPaginatedProducts is called and returns laptops data
and also
when I head to /motorcycle -> getPaginatedProducts is called and returns motorcycle data

The problem is, getPaginatedProducts function is always fired and returns data, but Next.js getStaticProps don't send data when url change.

Basicly, if I head to /laptops I get laptops data properly but if I head after that to /motorcycle the data inside [category].tsx remains the same(laptops). Only after page refresh data is properly fetched.

Is there any way around this or some other solution?

Answer (score 0):

`getStaticProps` fetches data at build time and you're trying to make use of something that's supplied at at request time and changes. Due to `revalidate` defaulting to false you're only seeing what gets cached the first time.

There, from the looks of it, you should use server-side rendering instead, take a look at this paragraph, [When should I use getServerSideProps?](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#when-should-i-use-getserversideprops) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63227604/how-to-get-param-from-url-in-getstaticprops-without-using-getstaticpaths).

Comment: Hii Nelloverflow and thanks for response. Yeah, it seems to be like that. I know about getServerSideProps but I was try to make it static as more as posible.

Comment: Funny thing, if i use getServerSideProps instead of staticSideProps, problem remains the same.

Comment: did you try getStaticPath ?
 https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths